# Is there a way to identify x64 and x86 Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, x86, 64-bit

**Machine Details**: Windows Server 2008 64 bit.

**Requirement**: I need to run applet on IE browser.

I am facing problem in opening applet in IE. It could be a problem of JVM installation. Please suggest me how can I identified correct IE browser installed in 64 bit OS.

Does anyone have any kind of code snippet that will help us to identify **x86/x64** browser. So we can easily fix client side problem related to applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading an article and I found one related to this requirement. I think It would be really useful.

you can easily detect IE browser whether it is on x86/ x64 bit using javascript.

**64-bit IE on 64-bit Windows:**

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0)

**32-bit IE on 64-bit Windows:**

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0)

Sample code: -

```
function browserVersion()
{
    alert(navigator.appVersion);
}
```

Comment: I think it is easy and very convenient way to identified IE version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that what you actually need is the arch of the JRE running on the client machine, I believe this will be helpful: [how to detect browser and OS in Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120155/how-to-detect-browser-and-os-in-java-applet).

Also check if you can run your applet with IE Security modes(Protected Mode(Security tab) and Enhanced Protected Mode(Advanced tab)) disable.

Regards.