# Getting System Info via html or java?

Tags: java, html, system-information

I'm trying to create a page that you can visit which will display system information. Such as the OS, host name, user name, domain, system make/model, etc. What would be the best way to go about this? I assume it can't simply be done via html, would java be the best option? Any suggestions? Mainly I simply want the user to not have to download an app or anything in order to get the information and have it displayed on the site. Something like allowing java to run would be acceptable though.

Comment: You can't, and it's a good thing websites have no way to get all this information from their visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The following site shows the sort of information that you can get about a client machine simply through the browser. Remember that any information you get through the browser is "non-authoratitive" (i.e. can be spoofed).

http://www.stayinvisible.com/

This includes the Operating System, Location and lots of details about the Browser and capabilities.

You can get more information by using a Java Applet, asking for browser plugins to be installed, or having an application download.

Answer (score 0):

If a Java applet is acceptable you might find (part of) your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120155/how-to-detect-browser-and-os-in-java-applet).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using PHP: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser). It can also be done in JavaScript `navigator.userAgent`. Though, it only gives OS and browser.

Just keep in mind that userAgent can be faked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use one library called Sugar, in this link you can download the needed files to read system information

Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/

Answer (score 0):

> In order to get System details of users using Html and JavaScript, use the below code.
> **The code does not perform any kind of mailicious activity**

*I have written this code for one of my projects as "system details".*

ignore styling and style it as per you choice

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>System Details</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">  
    <meta name="author" content="">

   <!-- mobile specific metas
   ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- CSS
   ================================================== -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">  
       

   <!-- script
   ================================================== -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

   <!-- favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

<style> 
        body { 
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: georgia;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.2;
}
    span{
        color:red;
    }
</style>
     
    </style> 
<style> 
        p { 
            
            color: green; 
        } 
    </style> 
    <style> 
        h3 { 
            word-spacing: 200;
            color: red; 
        } 
    </style> 
    <style> 
        h4 { 
            
            color: yellow; 
        } 
    </style> 
    <script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script> 
  
    <script> 
        /* Add "https://api.ipify.org?format=json" statement 
           this will communicate with the ipify servers in 
           order to retrieve the IP address $.getJSON will 
           load JSON-encoded data from the server using a 
           GET HTTP request */ 
  
        $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", 
                                          function(data) { 
  
            // Setting text of element P with id gfg 
            $("#gfg").html(data.ip); 
        }) 
    </script> 
<body id="body", onload="getLocation(),getHeaders()">
    
<hr/ style="color: red;">
<h3>_-_-_-Your System Details_-_-_-</h3>
<style>
    h2{
    
        color:green;
    }
</style>
<hr/ style="color: red;">
<br>
<hr/style="color: green;">
PAGE DETAILS
<p id="demo-1"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo-1").innerHTML ="<span>Page URL is : </span>" + window.location.href;
</script>

<p id="demo-2"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo-2").innerHTML ="<span>Page hostname is : </span>" + window.location.hostname;
</script>

<p id="demo-3"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo-3").innerHTML ="<span>Page pathname is : </span>" + window.location.pathname;
</script>

<p id="demo-4"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo-4").innerHTML ="<span>Page protocol is : </span>" + window.location.protocol;
</script>
<p id="demo-5"></p>
<script>
document.write("<span>This site was last updated on </span>" + document.lastModified); 
</script>


<hr/style="color: green;">
<br>
<hr/style="color: white;">
MOUSE LOCATION<BR>
<br>
 <div id='info'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  // Getting 'Info' div in js hands
var info = document.getElementById('info');

// Creating function that will tell the position of cursor
// PageX and PageY will getting position values and show them in P
function tellPos(p){
  info.innerHTML = '<span>Your Cursor is at Position X : </span>' + p.pageX + ' <span>Position Y : </span>' + p.pageY;
}
addEventListener('mousemove', tellPos, false);
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
  * {

  /*transition: 0.2s all ease;*/
  }

</style>

<hr/style="color: white;">



<style>
    note{
        color:blue;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>
<style>
    note1{
        color:cyan;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>
<br>
<hr/style="color: blue;">
<nm style="color: white;">BROWSER DETAILS</nm>
<br><br>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =
"<span>App-Name is :</span>" + navigator.appName + "<span>, App-Code-Name is: </span>" + navigator.appCodeName + "<span>, Browser Engine is: </span> " + navigator.product;
</script>



<p id="demo33"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo33").innerHTML =
"<span>your product sub is: </span> " + navigator.productSub;
</script>



<p id="demo333"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo333").innerHTML =
"<span>your vendor is: </span> " + navigator.vendor+ "<and> & </and>"+ "<span>your vendor sub is: </span> " + navigator.vendorSub;
</script>


<p id="demo4"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML ="<span>Browser version is: </span> " + navigator.appVersion + "<span>, Browser platform is: </span> " + navigator.platform;
</script>



<p id="demo666"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo666").innerHTML = "<span>Hardware concurrency is: </span> " + navigator.hardwareConcurrency + "<span>, Build ID is: </span> " + navigator.buildID;
</script>


<p id="demo5"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = "<span>your Browser is: </span> " + navigator.userAgent;
</script>


<p id="demo7"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo7").innerHTML ="<span>your Browser languages are: </span> " + navigator.languages;
</script>




<p id="demo0"></p>
<style>
    p{
        color:purple;
        text-transform: uppercase;      
    }
</style>
<style>
    span{
        color:orange;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>
<style>
    and{
        color:blue;
        
    }
</style>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML =
"<span>Cookie enabled is: </span>" + navigator.cookieEnabled+"<and> &</and>"+"<span> Java Enabled is: </span>" +navigator.javaEnabled();;
</script>


<p id="demo011"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo011").innerHTML =
"<span>Do not track (1 (ON) & 0 (OFF)): </span>" + navigator.doNotTrack;
</script>

<hr/style="color: blue;">
<br>
<hr/style="color: orange;">
SCREEN & DEVICE DETAILS
<p id="demo10"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo10").innerHTML ="<span>Screen Width: </span>" + screen.width;
</script>

<p id="demo11"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo11").innerHTML ="<span>Screen Height: </span>" + screen.height;
</script>



<b><p id="demo9"></p></b>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo9").innerHTML ="<span>Screen Resolution: </span>" + screen.width +"<span> x </span>"+screen.height;
</script>
    
<p id="demo12"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML =" <span>Available Screen Width: </span>" + screen.availWidth;
</script>

<p id="demo13"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo13").innerHTML ="<span> Available Screen Height: </span>" + screen.availHeight;
</script>

<p id="demo131"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo131").innerHTML ="<span> Orientation: </span>" + screen.orientation.type;
</script>

<p id="demo14"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo14").innerHTML ="<span>Screen Color Depth: </span>" + screen.colorDepth+"<and> & </and>"+"<span>Screen Pixel  Depth: </span>" + screen.pixelDepth;
</script>

<p id="-6"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android|Tablet/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        var element = document.getElementById('-6');
        if (isMobile) {
            element.innerHTML = "<span>You are using: </span> Mobile";
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = "<span>You are using: </span> Desktop";
        }
    </script>

<p id="demo66"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo66").innerHTML = "<span>your oscpu (Operating System | CPU) is: </span> " + navigator.oscpu;
</script>

<p id="demo78"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo78").innerHTML = "<span>your device memory is: </span> " + navigator.deviceMemory;
</script>
<hr/style="color: orange;">
<BR>
<hr/style="color: purple;">

BATTERY STATUS
<article class="battery-card">
      <h1 class="battery-title"></h1>

      <div class="battery-box">
        <strong class="battery-percentage"></strong>
        <i class="battery"></i>
      </div>

      <dl class="battery-info">
        <dt><span>Power Source</span></dt>
        <dd class="battery-status"><p>---</p></dd>

        <dt><span>Level percentage</span></dt>
        <dd class="battery-level"><p>---</p></dd>

        <dt><span>Fully charged in</span></dt>
        <dd class="battery-fully"><p>---</p></dd>

        <dt><span>Remaining time</span></dt>
        <dd class="battery-remaining"><p>---</p></dd>
      </dl>

    </article>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var battery;

  function toTime(sec) {
    sec = parseInt(sec, 10);

    var hours = Math.floor(sec / 3600),
        minutes = Math.floor((sec - (hours * 3600)) / 60),
        seconds = sec - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours < 10) { hours   = '0' + hours; }
    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = '0' + minutes; }
    if (seconds < 10) { seconds = '0' + seconds; }

    return hours + ':' + minutes;
  }

  function readBattery(b) {
    battery = b || battery;

    var percentage = parseFloat((battery.level * 100).toFixed(2)) + '%',
        fully,
        remaining;

    if (battery.charging && battery.chargingTime === Infinity) {
      fully = '<p>Calculating...</p>';
    } else if (battery.chargingTime !== Infinity) {
      fully = toTime(battery.chargingTime);
    } else {
      fully = '---';
    }

    if (!battery.charging && battery.dischargingTime === Infinity) {
      remaining = '<p>Calculating...</p>';
    } else if (battery.dischargingTime !== Infinity) {
      remaining = toTime(battery.dischargingTime);
    } else {
      remaining = '<p>---<?p>';
    }

    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.battery:before{width:' + percentage + '}', 0);
    document.querySelector('.battery-percentage').innerHTML = percentage;
    document.querySelector('.battery-status').innerHTML = battery.charging ? '<p>Adapter (charging)</p>' : '<p>Battery (not charging)</p>';
    document.querySelector('.battery-level').innerHTML = percentage;
    document.querySelector('.battery-fully').innerHTML = fully;
    document.querySelector('.battery-remaining').innerHTML = remaining;

  }

  if (navigator.battery) {
    readBattery(navigator.battery);

  } else if (navigator.getBattery) {
    navigator.getBattery().then(readBattery);

  } else {
    document.querySelector('.not-support').removeAttribute('hidden');
  }

  window.onload = function () {
    battery.addEventListener('chargingchange', function() {
      readBattery();
    });

    battery.addEventListener("levelchange", function() {
      readBattery();
    });
  };
}());
</script>
<hr/style="color: purple;">
<br>

<hr/style="color: cyan;">

DATE & TIME 


<p>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

now= new Date();

localtime=now.toString();

utctime =now.toUTCString();

document.write("<span>your local time is:</span>" + localtime +"<BR>");
document.write("<br><span>UTC time (Actual) is:</span>" + utctime);

</script>

</p>
<hr/style="color: cyan;">
<br>

<hr/style="color: green;">
IP ADDRESS
    


        <p><span>Your Public IP Address is:</span>
        <p id="gfg"></p>  





<span>Your Private / Local Machine IP</span><br><br>
<div id="-9"></div> 
<style>
div{
    color: purple;
}
</style>
<style>
iv{
    color: purple;
}
</style>
<script >  
    var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;  
if (RTCPeerConnection)(function() {  
    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({  
        iceServers: []  
    });  
    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {  
        rtc.createDataChannel('', {  
            reliable: false  
        });  
    };  
    rtc.onicecandidate = function(evt) {  
        if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);  
    };  
    rtc.createOffer(function(offerDesc) {  
        grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);  
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);  
    }, function(e) {  
        console.warn("offer failed", e);  
    });  
    var addrs = Object.create(null);  
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;  
  
    function updateDisplay(newAddr) {  
        if (newAddr in addrs) return;  
        else addrs[newAddr] = true;  
        var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function(k) {  
            return addrs[k];  
        });  
        document.getElementById('-9').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" |or perhaps| ") || "n/a";  
    }  
  
    function grepSDP(sdp) {  
        var hosts = [];  
        sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function(line) {  
            if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {  
                var parts = line.split(' '),  
                    addr = parts[4],  
                    type = parts[7];  
                if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);  
            } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {  
                var parts = line.split(' '),  
                    addr = parts[2];  
                updateDisplay(addr);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
})();  
else {  
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig| grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";  
    document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.";  
} 
</script>
<hr/style="color: green;">
<br>

<hr/style="color: blue;">
YOUR LOCATION<br>
<style>
  clk{
    color: green;
  }
</style>
<note1>Note:</note1> <clk>(Click here)</clk><note> to check your Location (Browser Based).</note>
<body onclick="getLocation()">

<p id="22"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("22");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "<span>Geolocation is not supported by this browser.</span>";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "<span>Latitude: </span>" + position.coords.latitude +"<and> & </and>"+ "<span>Longitude: </span>" + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
<hr/style="color: blue;">
<br>
<hr/>
NETWORK DETAILS<br><br>

<div id="network"></div>
<script>
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("<span>IP: </span>" + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("<span>Location: </span>" + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  hr, pre{
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div><br>
<span>Full response: </span><pre id="details"></pre>




<hr/>
FURTHER MORE NETWORK DETAILS
<div id="000"></div>
<script>
  $.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function (response) {
  $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
  $("#country").html('Country: ' + response.country_name);
  $("#region").html('Region ' + response.region);
  $("#city").html('City' + response.city);  
}, "jsonp");
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country"></div>
<div id="region"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<pre id="response"></pre>

<hr/style="color: red;">
<br>
<hr/style="color: yellow;">
HTTP HEADERS<BR>

<style type="text/css">
    
    c{
        line-height: 1;
        color: purple;
    }
</style>
<c id="demoz"></c>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function getHeaders() {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);

// associate array to store all values
var data = new Object();

// get all headers in one call and parse each item
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
var aHeaders = headers.split('\n');
var i =0;
for (i= 0; i < aHeaders.length; i++) {
    var thisItem = aHeaders[i];
    var key = thisItem.substring(0, thisItem.indexOf(':'));
    var value = thisItem.substring(thisItem.indexOf(':')+1);
    data[key] = value;
}       

// get referer
var referer = document.referrer;
data["Referer"] = referer;

//get useragent
//var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
//data["UserAgent"] = useragent;


//extra code to display the values in html
var display = "";
for(var key in data) {
    if (key != "")
    display += "<span>" + key + "</span> : " + data[key] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demoz").innerHTML =  display;  
   }    

</script>
<br>
<hr/style="color: yellow;">
<br>

<hr/style="color: blue;">
VPN OR BAD KNOWN IP

<div id="results">
      <p id="detection-result"></p>
      <div>
        <h4 class="result"></h4>
        <span id="browser-timezone" class="result"></span>
        <h4 class="result"></h4>
        <span id="ip-timezone" class="result"></span>
        <span id="error-detail" class="error"></span>
      </div>
      
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function detectVPN() {
  var browserTimezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone

  return fetch(`https://ipapi.co/json`)
  .then(function(response) { return response.json() })
  .then(function (data) { 
    var ipTimezone = data.timezone
    console.log(`browser timezone: ${browserTimezone}`, `ip timezone: ${ipTimezone}`)
    return {
      browser: browserTimezone,
      ip: ipTimezone,
      usingVPN: ipTimezone != browserTimezone
    }
  })
}

detectVPN()
.then(function(detectionResult) {
  var body = document.getElementById('body')
  var result = document.getElementById('detection-result')
  var details = document.getElementsByClassName('result')

  detectionResult.usingVPN ? result.textContent = "You are using a VPN or Known Bad IP" : result.textContent = "You are not using a VPN or Known Bad IP"
  detectionResult.usingVPN ? body.style.backgroundColor = 'black' : body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
  body.style.color = 'white'
  
  document.getElementById("browser-timezone").textContent = detectionResult.browser
  document.getElementById("ip-timezone").textContent = detectionResult.ip
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(details, d => d.style.display = 'block')
})
.catch(function(err) {
  var body = document.getElementById('body')
  var result = document.getElementById('detection-result')
  var details = document.getElementsByClassName("error")
  var errorDetail = document.getElementById('error-detail')
  
  result.textContent = "There was an error detecting your VPN"
  errorDetail.textContent = err.message
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(details, d => d.style.display = 'block')
})
    </script>
    <br>
<hr/style="color: blue;">
TOR<br><br>
<div id="tor-browser-test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isTorBrowser() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // Creates a black 1x1 px image
    img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    return imagedata.data[0] == 255 
                && imagedata.data[1] == 255
                && imagedata.data[2] == 255
                && imagedata.data[3] == 255;
}

document.getElementById('tor-browser-test').innerHTML = isTorBrowser() ? 'Is Tor' : 'Not Tor';
</script>
    
<hr/style="color: blue;">
<br>

<hr/style="color: orange;">
LOADING TIME<br><br>
<script type="text/javascript">  
     var before_loadtime = new Date().getTime();  
     window.onload = Pageloadtime;  
     function Pageloadtime() {  
         var aftr_loadtime = new Date().getTime();  
         // Time calculating in seconds  
         pgloadtime = (aftr_loadtime - before_loadtime) / 1000  
  
         document.getElementById("loadtime").innerHTML = "The results are fetched in <font color='purple'><b>" + pgloadtime + "</b></font> Seconds ";  
     }  
</script>

<div>  
<span id="loadtime"></span>
<br>


<hr/style="color: orange;">






<div class="credits" style="font-family: comic;">
                        <p style="color: silver; text-transform: lowercase;"><cpy1 style="color: white; text-transform: capitalize;">Copyright &copy 2020 | </cpy1> <cpy><cpy2 style=" text-transform: lowercase; color: white;">cqr</cpy2><cpy3 style="color: darkorange; text-transform: capitalize; ">Cyber</cpy3>.xyz  </cpy></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                  

            </div> <!-- /row -->                    
           </footer>

        </div> <!-- /content-wrap -->
   
   </main> <!-- /main-404-content -->

   <div id="preloader"> 
        <div id="loader"></div>
   </div> 

   <!-- Java Script
   ================================================== --> 
   <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```